# Increase touchscreen sensitivity on Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, touchscreen, stylus

Is there a way to increase the touchscreen sensitivity on a stock Nexus 7? I ask because I find that there is no stylus that registers movement or even touching quickly and reliably. that means that it's useless for scribbling handwritten notes. Perhaps this is a stylus issue, or even on that can be solved in software. But the obvious solution would be something general that increased or tweaked the sensitivity of the screen. Does that exist?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using your fingers or a stylus does not make any a difference in responsiveness.

On Skitch, the drawing matches with what you swipe / touch / move, but the responsiveness is slow. Quill is faster (try it, if you still haven't), but it slightly changes what you draw; still faster than Skitch though.

All in all, I think this is probably a hardware issue; could be software too. Nevertheless, we both agree that there is an impedance mismatch!